# TransformControls + material + transparent:true = :-(

Tags: three.js, controls, transparent

When I attach the TransformControls to a mesh containing materials with transparent:true, the Transform Control object is ALWAYS placed 'behind' the object it is attached to - meaning, you cannot see it behind the object. This appears to be a bug.

How can I resolve this? 
Three.js version = v85
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hxln.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

The solution is to set the renderOrder property of the attached object to -1. This will always place the attached object behind the transformControls object. Adjusting transparency (opacity) of the object material will work fine after that.

- Villmer

Answer (score 0):

You can try sidewise rendering.. since here it is mendatory to appear the **front side only** (to ignore the backview) you can try

```
Three.MeshYourMaterial({side:THREE.FrontSide})
```

or

```
 Three.MeshYourMaterial({side:THREE.BackSide})
```

may be among two of them one can be worked....

Comment: Didn't work.
These had no affect.
side:THREE.BackSide
side:THREE.FrontSide
side:THREE.DoubleSide

Comment: Having transparent materials on a mesh for which the TransformControls are attached will visually push the controls BEHIND the object.

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'face.gif', render );
    texture.mapping = THREE.UVMapping;
    texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 250, 250, 250 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture } );
    material.transparent = true;
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
control.attach(mesh)

Comment: try to reduce the opacity i.e.

material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture } ); material.transparent = true; 
mateiral.opacity = 0.9 // or less than 1.0

Comment: The point of this post is to emphasize that setting material.transparent=true places the transformControls behind the object. Yes, you can reduce the opacity of the attached object to see the controls behind it but that's not the point. The transform controls should remain 'in front' of the object even when the opacity is set to 1.